# Kotlin Sublist Out of Bounds

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm currently trying to implement timsort algorithm on Kotlin and found java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException whenever I'm trying to run array size of 100000 and minrun of 49.

Here's my algorithm :

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> List<T>.timSort(): List<T> {
    var newList = this.toMutableList()
    var n = newList.size
    var minrun = 49

    var minruninc = minrun
    for (i in (0 until n step(minruninc))) {
        var x = 0
        var arrayElement = insertionSort(newList.slice(i until (i + minruninc)))
        for (y in i until (i + minruninc)) {
            newList[y] = arrayElement[x]
            x += 1
        }
    }

    var minruninc1 = minrun
    while (minruninc1 < n){
        for (i in 0 until n step(2 * minruninc1)) {
            var x = 0
            var arrayMerge = merge((newList.slice(i until i + minruninc1)),
                (newList.slice(i + minruninc1 until i + 2 * minruninc1)))
            for (y in i until (i + 2 * minruninc1)) {
                newList[y] = arrayMerge[x]
                x += 1
            }
        }
        minruninc1 *=2
    }
    return newList
}
```

The line
`var arrayElement = insertionSort(newList.slice(i until (i + minruninc)))` returns out IndexOutOfBounds. When the `i` in for loop is set to 99960, the `(i + minrun)` returns a value of 100009, which causes the program to trigger the problem.

But, I need the algorithm to work when `(i + minrun)` is set every loop. The program sorts every minrun value of the list's element.

My question is, how can I control the last indexing part of the sorting algorithm so whenever `(i + minrun)` is more than array size, the indexing stops at exactly array size, not crossing the bounds?

Thank you.

Every help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you just looking for the `min` function? `min(i + minrun, newList.size())`

Comment: Not python - tag removed.

Comment: Ah, yes. Forgot about the min. Thank you Sweeper!